# Create a view in SQL setting values

Tags: mysql, view

I have this exercise to do but I don't know how to do the last part.

Create a view from the courses that the students have coursed from engineering or computer science. Include the name of the student, major and the name of the course. If the major of the student is "Computer Science", it should show "Science" and if the major is "Computer Engineering" it should show "Engineering" in the column major

I already have this, but I don't know how to set the values of science or engineering

```
 select sname
      , major 
      , cname
   from student 
natural 
   join enrolled
  where major = 'Computer Science' 
     or major = 'Computer Engineering'
```

Comment: I've not needed to use a natural join yet. I think that if you operate on the principle that there are exactly two types of join: JOIN and LEFT JOIN, you won't go too far wrong.

Comment: In fact, best forget about `natural joins` all together. What happens in production is someone adds a table column that matches name months-years down the track and the query suddenly changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about IF?

```
CREATE view MyView as
SELECT sname
    , IF(major = 'Computer Science', 'Science', 'Engineering') as major
    , cname
FROM student INNER JOIN enrolled ON ______
WHERE major = 'Computer Science'
    OR major = 'Computer Engineering'
```

I think you'd only need the 1 IF because you're already limiting records to 2 types in your `WHERE`.

You'd also need to complete the `JOIN`.